# Print a map with markers

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I tried to print a MapBox with markers (from Chrome and Edge latest versions) and the markers are replaced by a white area.

To ensure it's not related to my code, I checked this page: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons and when I try to print it, I have the same behavior:

[Normal web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIzHm.png)

in print mode (Chrome here but same in Edge):

[Print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4k0g.png)

So it's hiding the 3 markers but also the Mapbox logo at the bottom.

Any idea on how to keep the images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under "More settings" > "Options", Chrome has an option for printing "Background graphics". When this is unchecked, any css elements that use the background-image attribute will be blank when printed.

To address this, add a short set of css for the print version which includes a pseudo "before" class to insert the marker image and code to remove the background image for the normal ".marker" class:

```
@media print {
    .marker::before {
        content: url('images/orangepin2.png');
    }
    .marker {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least for the MapBox logo, adding this style to the MapBox container worked for me:

```
.printable-map {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

This bypasses the checkbox that the user has to select to force the logo to print. This works for other elements with backgrounds as well.